# Set .m2 for a single build-job to different location

Tags: java, maven

For a build-job on a build-server, I want to set the `.m2` location to something different from `user.home/.m2`.

I thought I could trick maven by setting `export HOME=$WORKSPACE` for the build, but artifacts kept being downloaded and being deployed to the build user's home directory.

Therefore I think that maven uses the `user.home` system property which seems to not take `$HOME` into account.

Is there a solution for this? We have a local maven cache, and I do want to download all artifacts for this build-job and prevent any deployment into the build-user's `$HOME/.m2` in order to seperate individual build jobs from each other. At least I want this for some jobs.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the location of the settings.xml file from the command line...

```
mvn <target> --settings /path/to/settings.xml
```

From here you can customize anything you would need.

*[update] You can even override the "global" settings which are typically merged with the user's settings.xml form their .m2 directory via `--global-settings /path/to/global/settings.xml`*

Comment: Can I set this via an environment variable somehow? If possible I'd like to configure the build scripts without actually changing the build files. But that would just be nice-to-have. :)

Comment: @Martin C.: I don't know how you are kicking off the build scripts so I can't say.

Comment: Most of it via shell scripts on a Jenkins server, as there are additional pre-processing steps necessary for those where I'd like to modify the .m2 location. Some are buildr jobs, some are Gradle jobs. Buildr is configurable in this regard, but Gradle uses default maven, as it seems.

Comment: I don't know about those directly; perhaps you could pose a new question regarding Gradle and reference this question.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to specify your own local repository you can use the option `maven.repo.local` :

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/your/repository
```

---

**Resources :**

- [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/properties.html) (on maven-1.x website but still works with maven 3.0 - can't find a reliable source for this version though)